# I am trying to implement the drag and drop feature. I am trying to fix it, and nothing is helping even thought the structure is correct

Tags: typescript, react-tsx

I have 2 files and I downloaded 2 packages 1) npm i react-beautiful-dnd 2) npm i @types/react-beautiful-dnd

I have 2 files, the draggable and the droppable.
-The Draggable: SingleTodo.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Todo } from './model'
import { AiFillDelete, AiFillEdit } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { MdDone } from 'react-icons/md'
import "../../../styles/SingleTodo.css"
import { JSX } from 'react/jsx-runtime'
import { Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

type Props = {
    index: number;
    todo:Todo;
    todos:Todo[];
    setTodos:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Todo[]>>;
}

  const SingleTodo = ({index ,todo, todos, setTodos}: Props) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [editTodo, setEditTodo] = useState<string>(todo.todo);  
  
  const handleDone = (id:number) => {
    setTodos(todos.map((todo) => todo.id === id ? {...todo, isDone: !todo.isDone} : todo))
  };

  const handleDelete = (id:number) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id))
  };
  const handleEdit = (e:React.FormEvent, id:number) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos(todos.map((todo) => todo.id === id ? {...todo, todo: editTodo} : todo))
    setEdit(false);
  };
  
  const focusOnClick = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    focusOnClick.current?.focus();
  }, [edit]);
  
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId ={todo.id.toString()} index={index}>
      {
        (provided)=> (
          <form className="todosSingle" onSubmit={(e)=>handleEdit(e,todo.id)}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
          ref={provided.innerRef}>
      {
        edit? (
          <input 
          ref = {focusOnClick}
          value={editTodo}
           onChange={(e) => setEditTodo(e.target.value)} 
          className="todosSingleText" />
        ) : todo.isDone? (
          <s className="todosSingleText">{todo.todo}</s>
        ) : (
          <span className="todosSingleText">{todo.todo}</span>
        )
      }
      
      <div>
        <span className="icons" onClick={() => {
          if(!edit && !todo.isDone){
            setEdit(!edit)
        }
      }}><AiFillEdit/></span>
        <span className="icons" onClick={()=>handleDelete(todo.id)}><AiFillDelete/></span>
        <span className="icons" onClick={()=>handleDone(todo.id)}><MdDone/></span>
      </div>
    </form>
      )
        }
    </Draggable>
  );
};

export default SingleTodo;
```

-The Droppable: ToDoList.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Todo } from './model';
import "../../../styles/TodoList.css"
import SingleTodo from './SingleTodo';
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

interface Props{
        todos: Todo[];
        setTodos: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Todo[]>>;
        doneTodos: Todo[];
        setIsDoneTodos: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Todo[]>>;
}
const TodoList: React.FC<Props> = ({ todos, setTodos, doneTodos, setIsDoneTodos } : Props) => {
    return(
         <div className="container">
            <Droppable droppableId="TodossListtt">
            {(provided) => (
            <div className="todos"
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.droppableProps}>
            <span className="todosHeading">Current Tasks</span>
            {
                todos.map((todo, index) => (
                    <SingleTodo
                    index={index}
                    todo={todo}
                    todos={todos}
                    key={todo.id} 
                    setTodos={setTodos}
                    />
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
                )}
            </Droppable>
            
            <Droppable droppableId="DoneTodosListttt">
                {(provided)=>(
            <div className="todos delete"
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.droppableProps}>
            <span className="todosHeading">Completed</span>
            {
                doneTodos.map((todo, index) => (
                    <SingleTodo
                    index={index}
                    todo={todo}
                    todos={doneTodos}
                    key={todo.id}
                    setTodos={setIsDoneTodos}/>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
            </div>     
                    )}  
            </Droppable>
         </div>
    );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Honestly, I tried everything and nothing helped, it kept refusing to work. I truly appreciate any effort that could make this work.